# Django - The page don't load after click

Tags: python, django, templates

i'm new in Django developing.
I'm following the tutorial about Library on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django)
Until i follow the code all work but i'm trying implement author page by myself. Probably is very stupid issue but is one day that i'm turning around like a dog with its tail.
There is 2 page: author_list and author detail. 
I set `urls.py` (in my project) i set `view.py` and crate my template. 
I follow the same step of tutorial for realize book_list and book_detail but when i click on my author the page don't go to the detail of that author and stay in `author_list.html`.

Here the code urls.py :

```
path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name='authors'),
path('author/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='author-detail'),
```

Here views.py:

```
class AuthorListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author

class AuthorDetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Author
```

Here `author_list.html` with link `get_absolute_url`:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html"%}

{% block content %}

 <h1>Author list</h1>
{% if author_list %}
<ul>
    {% for aut in author_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ aut.get_absolute_url }}">{{ aut.first_name }} - {{ aut.last_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>There are no author.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here author_detail.html:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Author</h1>
{% if author %}
<p><strong>Nome: </strong> {{ author }}</p>
<p><strong>Nato il : </strong> {{ author.date_of_birth }}</p>
<p><strong>Morto il : </strong> {{ author.date_of_death }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here the screenshot

[Author_list.html before click url=catalog/authors/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZy87.png)

[After click url change but page not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSvDY.png)

Thank to all for help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) instead of ListView for AuthorDetailView.

Comment: Thanks to all for help. 
Sorry for this stupid question but i break my head to read and reread code without see this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me, you want `generic.DetailView` (instead of `ListView`) for the `author/<int:pk>` path.

I also don't think it's right to extend `base_generic` for the template for the detail view. But that depends exactly what is in this base template.

Comment: Thanks to all for help. 
Sorry for this stupid question but i break my head to read and reread code without see this detail.